# Google app engine nullpointerexception when trying to fetch list instead of searching by primary key

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, ubuntu-12.04, google-cloud-endpoints

I am just starting out on GAE and cloud endpoints. I have created a sample persistent class and I generated the enpoint class using the google menu in Eclipse. Now I was just following some tutorial on how to use `curl` and get back nice `json` string and apparently when I trying to list all values its throwing a `nullpointerexception`, surprisingly when I provide an id with the url string then it magically works. Now, my concern is with this two method viz `listContinent` and `getContinent`

This is what is creating the error

```
 curl http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/app/v1/continent
```

which is calling the `listContinent` method raising the error.

and this one just works

```
 curl http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/app/v1/continent/1
```

which is calling the `getContinent` method and when the correct `Id` is passed via the url it works as expected.

This is my endpoint class -

```
@Api(name = "app")
public class ContinentEndpoint {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "cast", "unchecked" })
    public List<Continent> listContinent() {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        List<Continent> result = new ArrayList<Continent>();
        try {
            Query query = mgr.newQuery(Continent.class);
            for (Object obj : (List<Object>) query.execute()) {
                result.add(((Continent) obj));
            }
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Continent getContinent(@Named("id") Long id) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        Continent continent = null;
        try {
            continent = mgr.getObjectById(Continent.class, id);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return continent;
    }

    private static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager() {
        return PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    }

}
```

and this is my persistent class -

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
@Version(strategy = VersionStrategy.VERSION_NUMBER)
public class Continent {

    public long getContinentId() {
        return continentId;
    }

    public void setContinentId(long continentId) {
        this.continentId = continentId;
    }

    public String getContinentName() {
        return continentName;
    }

    public void setContinentName(String continentName) {
        this.continentName = continentName;
    }

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private long continentId;
    private String continentName;
    private Date createdOn = new Date();
}
```

This is my stacktrace

```
Nov 12, 2012 3:07:10 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Nov 12, 2012 3:07:10 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /home/soham/Workspace/cloudcv/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Nov 12, 2012 3:07:10 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /home/soham/Workspace/cloudcv/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
Nov 12, 2012 8:37:11 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Nov 12, 2012 8:37:11 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Nov 12, 2012 8:37:53 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.fetchLongField(QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.java:74)
    at org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityUtils.getApplicationIdentityForResultSetRow(IdentityUtils.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1009)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:228)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:225)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult$LazyAbstractListIterator.computeNext(LazyResult.java:229)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:131)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult$AbstractListIterator.hasNext(LazyResult.java:183)
    at com.cloudcv.ContinentEndpoint.listContinent(ContinentEndpoint.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:254)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:135)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:106)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I did some debugging and I found out that the query in `Query query = mgr.newQuery(Continent.class);` is not returning anything and the `for each` loop is not populating the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Showing your code would make it a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: Did you unit test the method listContinent and is it working as it should be?

Comment: @SajanChandran Just as I said I was watching this Google I/O event and following instructions - [Google I/O 2012 - HTML5 and App Engine: The Epic Tag Team Take on Modern Web Apps at Scale](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WkLO-q2wC80). I just did what the guys showed and I'm an absolute novice in google app engine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use `long` as the primary key type. I'd suggest using `Long` instead. You can read about the acceptable key types [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Keys).

Comment: Brilliant. Wasted nearly 3 days trying to figure this out.